# Can't connect to wifi internet network if other device is connected to router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ping

I'm having an unusual network issue. My laptop (Macbook Air 13", 2016) works fine on any network it connects on, except for one (My home router).

Indeed, my laptop actually can connect to the internet, only when one specific laptop is disconnected to that router. Once that laptop is connected, my laptop says it's connected to wifi, but no internet can be accessed (This behavior only appeared only recently). This behavior is present in some other devices (Android phone) but not on others (2012 iPad). Here's what happens when I'm trying to ping 8.8.8.8

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
```

I checked the modem's configuration, but nothing seems out of the ordinary. I also tried assigning a static IP address instead of using DHCP, but nothing seems to work.

Connecting to the router with an ethernet cable works.

I'm trying to figure out what could be the root cause of this problem in order to find a solution to it.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Install Wireshark or tcpdump and check what device is responding to DHCP queries, and what destination MAC address your points are being sent to. Compare the working and non-working cases.

Comment: Did you set a custom DHCP client ID on both machines, and not realize you set them both to the same value?

Answer (score 0):

This initially sounded like an IP address conflict between the two wireless clients; however, the problem persisted after forcing one device to use a static, presumably different, IP address⁠—so it can't be that. (Be sure that the statically assigned IP is different to the one previously obtained through DHCP.)

1) Check the MAC address of both wireless devices, just to rule out a duplicate MAC address as an issue. They are supposed to be unique but that isn't always the case.

2) If the MAC addresses are different, try performing a factory reset of your router and seeing if the problem persists.